# How can I create virtual subdomain which points to a folder?

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, subdomain

I am trying to create a website that would create its portfolio, currently once created your page that has the URL `domain.com/content/username` but I would like to create a subdomain for each user therefore `username.domain.com`. Do you have any idea how to do this? I tried this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
#
# Canonicalize the hostname
RewriteCond www.%{HTTP_HOST} ^(www)\.(mine-app\.fr) [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^.]+)\.(mine-app\.fr) [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.www\.(mine-app\.fr) [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.(mine-app\.fr). [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.(mine-app\.fr):[0-9]+
RewriteRule (.*) http://%1.%2/$1 [R=301,L]
#
# If subdomain is NOT www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mine-app\.fr [NC]
# Extract (required) subdomain to %1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.mine-app\.fr$
# Rewrite if requested URL resolves to existing file or subdirectory in /content/<content>/ path
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/content/%1/$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/content/%1/$1 -d
RewriteRule (.*) /content/%1/$1 [L]
```

But nothing worked. How can I solve this?

Comment: It's called virtual hosts and requires configuring Apache (or whatever your web server is running from) to set up the different hosting areas. Hope that points you in the right direction.

Comment: Looking closer at your question, I believe what you actually want is wildcard subdomains, so that is something your'd need to configure with your DNS and Apache.

Comment: If you use cPanel, it is quite easily done manually. Do you need it to be created automatically?

Comment: yes i want it to be created automatically, I already have configured my A records in my DNS but nothing worked. Should i look for htaccess or php ? i really don't understand what i can read on the internet